# Why QCamera::CaptureVideo isn't supported?

Tags: c++, qt, qtmultimedia

I'm trying to create an application which uses camera API, based on an example from Qt.

*Problem:*
Following call to check if *video capture* is supported returns `false`.

```
camera->isCaptureModeSupported(QCamera::CaptureVideo) //returns false.
```

If I try to ignore it and start recording - recording does not start and I get no error messages ( Also, `QMediaRecorder::errorString()` and `QCamera::errorString()` return empty strings ).

Image from camera correctly showed in `QCameraViewFinder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically is a known bug in windows.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-30541

https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.5/qtmultimedia-windows.html

It should work in other platforms, though.